# How do I make a table to hold the content in my design?

Tags: html, html-table

I created a design for my website. I am planning to make it with TABLES because it seems to be the easiest. The tables are not going the way I intended.

There was a problem putting the code on the page so I put my HTML document (.html) and the way I want it to look (.jpg) in the below zip-file link:

http://ericlounge.host22.com/000/22014/0aa.zip

If someone could give me  the code or explain my error that would be great!

Comment: Don't do it man! Put the tables down.

Comment: Code you insert in your question has to be indented by **four** spaces. You can link pictures, it is described in the here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Abusing tables for layout isn't really easier; they just look that way to people who have been doing it for a decade because they've already learned all the foibles of hacking that approach to look they way they want. Go and learn to do it right: http://wsc.opera.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using tables, but it's your choice.

```
<Table>
    <TR>
        <TD rowspan ="3">
            Navigation
        </TD>
        <TD>
           TITLE
        </TD>
        <TD rowspan ="3">
            SideBar
        </TD
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            ADS
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            Content
        </TD>
    </TR>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, however, it will give you reasons why you should look at a different approach for your layout/design rather than tables.

[Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/div-vs-table)

To counteract the "tables is the easiest" option then have a look at Yahoo's YUI templates and examples. These can probably produce exactly what you are after with little effort.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/